# sklearn NB classifier: How to get the actual probabilities of individual samples?

Tags: scikit-learn, probability, naivebayes, multinomial

I am making a machine learning program which classifies words in one of the following categories: Hardware, Software, None_of_these. I make use of the Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier from sklearn.

The function predict() gives me the prediction of every word, however, I can't see the actual probability (float ranging for 0 to 1.0) that the word matches with the predicted categorie. I didn't find this on sklearn's site either.

Is there a function which gives me the probability of every sample?

Comment: Btw can you explain how predict_proba calculating on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177954/multinomialnb-sklearn-joint-log-likelihood-and-predict-log-proba-give-me-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the solution.:

predict_proba(X)    Returns probability estimates for the test vector X.